# How to unmarshal <!DOCTYPE> section In JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I need to unmarshal **!DOCTYPE** section using JAXB so I can get the values of file1 and file2.

The xml file looks like this  :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <!DOCTYPE doc [
     <!ENTITY file1 SYSTEM "conf/files/file1.xml">
      <!ENTITY file2 SYSTEM "conf/files/file2.xml">
    ]>

    <appels>
      <appel>
         &file1;
      </appel>
      <appel>
         &file1;
       </appel>
    </appels>
```

the java look like this :

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "appels")
public class Appels implements Serializable {

private List<Appel> appel;

}
```

I need to get 
file1 = conf/files/file1.xml **and** 
file2 = conf/files/file2.xml

is this possible?
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

The following will resolve `&file1;` to the contents of the file `conf/files/file1.xml`.

```
<!ENTITY file1 SYSTEM "conf/files/file1.xml">
```

The following will resolve `&file3;` to the string `conf/files/file3.xml`.

```
<!ENTITY file3 "conf/files/file3.xml">
```

---

### Input Files

**input.xml**

This is a slightly modified version of the XML document from your question.  I changed one of the `&file1;` to `&file2;` and added `&file3;`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
    <!ENTITY file1 SYSTEM "conf/files/file1.xml">
    <!ENTITY file2 SYSTEM "conf/files/file2.xml">
    <!ENTITY file3 "conf/files/file3.xml">
 ]>
<appels>
    <appel>
         &file1;
    </appel>
    <appel>
         &file2;
    </appel>
    <appel>
         &file3;
    </appel>
</appels>
```

**conf/files/file1.xml**

```
<foo>Hello World</foo>
```

**conf/files/file2.xml**

Instead of making this an XML file, I'm just going to add text.

```
Foo Bar
```

### Equivalent XML File

As far as your parser is concerned your XML document looks like the following.  Note that `&file1;` and `&file2;` resolved to the contents of their files and `&file3;` did not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appels>
    <appel>
         <foo>Hello World</foo>
    </appel>
    <appel>
         Foo Bar
    </appel>
    <appel>
         conf/files/file3.xml
    </appel>
</appels>
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

The demo code below will convert the XML to objects, and then write it back to XML.  The entities are resolved when the XML is unmarshalled into objects.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Appels.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum20637070/input.xml");
        Appels appels = (Appels) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(appels, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Note how the first `appel` element marshalled. Since `&file;` resolved to an XML fragment, JAXB wasn't able to match it against the text property we had mapped.

```
<appels>
    <appel>
    </appel>
    <appel>
             Foo Bar
    </appel>
    <appel>
             conf/files/file3.xml
    </appel>
</appels>
```

### Java Model

Below is the Java model I used for this example:

**Appels**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "appels")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Appels implements Serializable {

    private List<Appel> appel;

}
```

**Appel**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Appel {

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

Comment: first thank you for your answer but what i need is not the the content of file1 and file2 but the path itself, meaning "conf/files/file1.xml" and "conf/files/file2.xml"

Comment: @hb.Sara - Then you should have `<!ENTITY file1 "conf/files/file1.xml" > ` and not `<!ENTITY file1 SYSTEM "conf/files/file1.xml">`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is what you're looking for: http://lauraliparulo.altervista.org/jaxb-part-6-entities-references-expansion-before-unmarshalling/

Comment: This solution don't seem to return
 <!DOCTYPE doc [
     <!ENTITY file1 SYSTEM "conf/files/file1.xml">
      <!ENTITY file2 SYSTEM "conf/files/file2.xml">
    ]>