# Attach a file to an XML file

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I have an XML file that I parse in Java using JAXB then I use the java object to call a web service. Now I need to attach a file to this XML file.

I know that it is possible to attach a file with SoapUI, but I need to o it in java.

I tried to include it this way (with `arg0` in java will be a `bytes[]`):

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY otherFile SYSTEM "test1Response.xml">]>
...
<urn:attachment>
    <urn:arg0>&otherFile;</urn:arg0>
    <urn:fileName>test1Response.xml</urn:fileName>
    <urn:typePJ>xml</urn:typePJ>
    <urn:comments>comments</urn:comments>
</urn:attachment>
```

But it does not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you are looking for the file path, then you should have <!ENTITY otherFile "test1Response.xml" ... there will not be SYSTEM.

Comment: No I need the content of the file.

Comment: Did you check this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637070/how-to-unmarshal-doctype-section-in-jaxb

Comment: So I need to have bytes in the `testResponse.xml` so that JAXB can match it with `bytes[]' in Java?